# How to rearrange the value of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table (tblDates). In this table I have two column (Date,Age) . Now I want If I add new date in this table then Age column rearranged there values.

Table - tblDates

```
Date           Age
--------------------
12/01/14        5
12/02/14        4
12/03/14        3
12/04/14        2 
12/05/14        1
```

If I add New date i.e., 12/06/14 then I want result like this

Table - tblDates

```
Date           Age
--------------------
12/01/14        6
12/02/14        5
12/03/14        4
12/04/14        3
12/05/14        2 
12/06/14        1
```

Comment: You need to define better how "Age" is calculated. Is it just a straight forward row numbering as ordered by date? What if there are duplicate or missing dates? Also why do you need to store this value?

Comment: Then put a clustered index on age with desc.  Why SQL, TSQL, 2008, and 2012.  It can't be all of that stuff.

Comment: the order of rows in a RDBMS is irrelevant. Use an ORDER BY clause to see the rows in a certain order.

Answer (score 1):

I may be reading too much into your question, but if your goal is to compute the age (in days) from a given date (today?) to the date stored in your tables, then you'll be better off using the [DATEDIFF function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) and computing the value when you query it each time.

For example:

```
-- Option 1: Compute when you query it each time in the query you require it
SELECT d.[Date], DATEDIFF(dd, d.[Date], CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) as [Age]
FROM tblDates AS d
```

You can also define the Age column on your table as a Computed Column if it will be used frequently enough, or wrap the table in a View to embed this computation:

```
-- Option 2: Compute at query time, but build the computation into the table definition
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDates] (
     [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
     [AgeInDaysComputed] AS (DATEDIFF(dd, [Date], CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) )
)
GO

-- Option 3: Compute at query time, but require caller interact with a different object 
--  (view) to get the computation
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwDates]
AS
SELECT d.[Date], DATEDIFF(dd, d.[Date], CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) as [AgeInDays]
  FROM dbo.tblDates AS D
GO
```

One note regarding the GETDATE function: you need to be aware of your server timezone, as GETDATE returns the date according to your server's local timezone.  As long as your server configuration and user's configurations are all in the same timezone, this should provide the correct result.

(If the age in days is what you're trying to compute, you may want to edit your question to better reflect this intent for the benefit of future readers, as it is quite different from "rearranging the value of columns")

Answer (score 0):

Pull the values that you want out when you query, not when you insert data.  You seem to want:

```
select d.*, row_number() over (order by date desc) as age
from tblDates d;
```

Otherwise, your insert operation will become very cumbersome, requiring changes to all the rows in the table.